# Sending an auto-filled Outlook email template from Excel with multiple cell text body and additional text formatting

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have an email template saved in Outlook. I send this email out many times a day. Each email I send is **formatted with bold, colored text, the company logo**, and unique information for that recipient.

The unique information is generated in excel and so what I have been manually copying and pasting the excel information into the Outlook template.

I want to figure out a way to get excel to auto-populate the template for me, including the main recipient, the cc recipient, subject, and attachment, and the cells pasted into the body of the email.

I know there is a way through mailings in Microsoft Word, but I can't figure out how to get it to automate completely. Then excel will do everything, but it **ignore all formatting in the text body** and I cant get it to **select multiple cells for the text body**.

I don't even know where to begin with this one. Below is the basic VBA for sending an email on outlook. But of course, the range for the email body doesnt work

```
Sub SupplierTestingEmail()

   Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
      Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        olMail.To = Range("B1")
        olMail.Subject = Range("B2")
        olMail.Body = Range("A1:C5")
        olMail.Display

End Sub
```

I want the email to include the following things

1) a range of cells for the body
2) the company logo
3) Colored text
4) referenced cells
5) an attachment
6) a carbon copy, I need to CC someone.

Comment: For your multiple cells part, why not just loop through them and build a string?

Comment: Does using `HTMLBody` instead of `Body` help at all?

Comment: HTMLBody still gave an error. and I don't know how to loop through them and build a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To Preserves original formatting once you copy the range, work with [Word object model with MailItem.GetInspector Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-getinspector-property-outlook) and then paste it as **`wdFormatOriginalFormatting`** [WdRecoveryType Enumeration (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/wdrecoverytype-enumeration-word)*

---

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)

' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document '<=========
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sht.Range("A4:H16").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.Copy

    With Email
        .To = Sht.Range("C1")
        .Subject = Sht.Range("B1")
        .Display

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    End With

End Sub
```

---

> *Excel*
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> *Outlook*
>
> [image]