# How do I add bullets to the .Body section of an email template?

Tags: html, vba, outlook, outlook-2010, bulletedlist

How do I add bullets into the `.Body` section of an email template?

I want my email body to look like below:

---

Attached are the docs for DATE AM.

Mailed

- 3 documents

Received

- 7 documents

---

My current code is below, except without the extra space underneath the words Mailed and Received:

```vb
Sub CreateNewMail()
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'You can change the concrete info as per your needs
    With NewMail
        .Subject = "Docs " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM"
        .To = 
        .Body = "Attached are the docs for " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
          & "Mailed" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
          & "Received"
         .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am fairly new to VBA. I searched forums but I can't find what I need.

Comment: You're going to need to look into incorporating HTML in your code if you want to do any sort of formatting. https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vba_excel.aspx?cat=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897439/4539709

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207287/4539709

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you will need to use HTML which can easily be achieved using .HTMLBody instead of .Body.  If all you need is a couple of bullets, you can keep it simple.  This should get you started.  You want an unordered list `<ul>` to which you will add a list item `<li>`

```
Sub CreateNewMail()
Dim obApp As Object
Dim NewMail As MailItem

Set obApp = Outlook.Application
Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'You can change the concrete info as per your needs
With NewMail
     .Subject = "Docs " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM"
     .To = "Mr Nobody"
     .HTMLBody = "Attached are the docs for " & Format(Date, "m.d.yy") & " AM" & _
     "<p>Mailed</p>" & _
     "<ul><li>3 Documents</li></ul>" & _
     "<p>Received</p>" & _
     "<ul><li>7 Documents</li></ul>"
     .Display
End With

Set obApp = Nothing
Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```