# Formatting email body from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have found the code below from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207287/4539709

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)

' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document '<=========
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sht.Range("A4:H16").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.Copy

    With Email
        .To = Sht.Range("C1")
        .Subject = Sht.Range("B1")
        .Display

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    End With

End Sub
```

I have come across an issue with the code in that after you send an email the rows remain selected as per attached. Is there anyway to clear this

Comment: Can you be more specific on the issue ? Does the code run but do nothing ? Does it refuse to run ? If so, what error type is raised ?

Comment: Hi Vincent, it doesn't run at all. When I try to assign it to a button it doesn't find the module.  Not sure if I can attach the sheet here?

Comment: You cannot assign this macro to a button.  If is a function with parameters.  You need a subroutine which sets the values of `mail`, `name`, `Msht`, `CCmail` and `CCperson`.

Comment: There are three types of VBA macro.  (1) A subroutine without parameters.  For example I could have a macro `DeleteOldEmails()`.  This macro deletes emails that are more than a year old from any folder.  It needs no parameters because what it does is fixed.  It gets today’s date from the operating system and scans down every folder looking for emails received more than year before today’s date.  The use can call subroutines like this.

Comment: (2) A subroutine with parameters.  For example I could have a macro `DeleteOldEmailsFromFolder(ByVal FolderName As String)`.  This macro deletes old emails from a named folder.  If the user wants to use this macro, they need subroutine `GetFolderNameAndDeleteOldEmails()`.  This subroutine asks the user for a folder name and then calls `DeleteOldEmailsFromFolder` to delete the emails.

Comment: (3) A function.  Most functions have parameters although it is not a requirement.  An example might be `HowManyOldEmailsAreThereInFolder(ByVal FolderName As String) As Integer `.  A function performs some task and returns a single value.  This macro scans all the folders and counts how many old emails there are and returns that count.  The user cannot call this function.  The user needs to call `GetFolderNameAndCountOldEmails()`

Comment: Your subroutine has parameters, for example: `Msht As Worksheet`.  `Msht` is a reference to a worksheet.   How does `sendMail` know which worksheet is the source of the values needed for the email?  It knows because the macro that calls it sets parameter `Msht` to the appropriate worksheet.

Comment: In the question you reference, the OP only provides the routine that does the work.  It does not include the macro that decides what work needs to be done.  The answerer has slightly modified the macro to include some Html.  Neither the question nor the answer is a complete routine.

Comment: @Tonydalimore I think I need to learn a bit more before it will work. :-(

Basically what I need it to do is send an email to two email addresses which is formatted from J1, J3, J5 and J7 in my sheet.  I found more code on rondebruin but whilst I can get it to run it doesn't format as I need.

Comment: Post code that you working on , post the results you get, post results you expect, pictures of the emails

Comment: @0m3r How do I add attachments?

Comment: @0m3r Thanks for your help with the code, I figured out what I was doing wrong and it now works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @TonyDallimore  Thanks for explaining the macros/functions. I think I understand. :-)

Comment: Hi @0m3r, I have come across an issue with the code in that after you send an email the rows remain selected as per attached. Is there anyway to clear this?

Comment: I will run test , then post answer later tonight

Comment: Hi @0m3r, did you have any luck? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Add the following line at the end [Application.CutCopyMode = False](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.cutcopymode)*

```
    With Email
        .To = Sht.Range("C1")
        .Subject = Sht.Range("B1")
        .Display

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False    '<---

End Sub
```