# Placing spreadsheet content in the body of an Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, paste

I'm having trouble getting the cells in my range to "paste" into the body of my email.

Prior to this endeavor I copied with VBA and had the users paste into the body.

There's a lot more to this macro, but I've trimmed it down to what I'm assuming are the relevant parts:

```vb
Dim LastRowCPsta As Long
If Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 33 Then
    LastRowCPsta = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Else
    LastRowCPsta = 33

' yadda yadda

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:S" & LastRowCPsta)
'Range("B1:S" & LastRowCPsta).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture

'blah blah

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Recipient
Dim Recipients As Recipients
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
Set objOutlookRecip = Recipients.Add("<redacted>")
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1
objOutlookMsg.Subject = EmailDate & " " & FileNaem
objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = rng.Address(False, False)
objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  
For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients
    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
Next
  
objOutlookMsg.Display
```

What ends up in the body of the email is a text value representing the range rather than the content of that range.

Comment: What sort of data is in the range you want to paste?

Comment: It's pass fail data, text and numbers, but all conditional formatted pretty specifically. Anything under a value is red, anything above is a gradient from red to yellow to green at 100.

Comment: looks like `objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = rng.Address(False, False)` is just grabbing the address of the range and not the value of the range.

Comment: see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49207287/4539709

Comment: @0m3r this worked great, ty. Only the report generators will need to add the reference library correct? I'll accept your answer just as soon as I figure out how to.